# nodejs: abort http reply while in progress

Tags: node.js, express

How do I abort http reply with express in the middle?
In my case I serve data that's generated from external source and before I start serving it I know the size (content-length). However, if external source stops feeding me the data before feeding me full content  I want to abort the request so that on receiver end there would be error event triggered.

Here's simple code, server:

```
//server
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
app.use(function(req, res, next){
    res.setHeader('Content-Length', 100);
    res.writeHead(200);
    res.write('1234567890');
    setTimeout(function() { res.connection.destroy(); }, 500);
});
app.listen(8080);
```

and

```
//client
var http = require('http');
http.get('http://localhost:8080/', function(res){
   var length = 0;
   console.log('expected size: ', res.headers['content-length']);
   res.on('data', function(chunk){ length += chunk.length; });
   res.on('end', function(){ console.log('received: ', length); });
}).on('error', function(e){
    console.log('error', e);
});
```

It's expected that client should show error that connection was reset and not behave as everything was ok even though only 10 bytes out of 100 were received.

How to abort connection on sender side when it's known that request cannot be fulfilled? One way I found out is to throw exception inside that timer, then receiver will log error, but I don't want to throw exception, I want to do it properly.

Comment: Hmm. I think you'd have to grab the full data from the external source before returning it from the node server.

Comment: @RobertMoskal not an option, I need to know hot to abort tcp connection. I can't believe there is no such method. I actually need to abort, no workarounds or other solutions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ideally to end an HTTP response, you would call `res.end()`.  In the cases of chunked transfer encoding or a connection without HTTP keep-alive, this will cleanly end the response.

However, most HTTP connections will support HTTP keep-alive, and since you have a `Content-Length` header, your transfer encoding isn't chunked.  In your case, you will have to close the underlying socket.  Check out the `req.connection` property, and call `.end()` on it.  This is undocumented but has been there for years and probably is safe for now.  More legitimate methods for getting the connection include [listening for it on the server object](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_event_connection), but then it's hard to associate the connection with the request.

You should be aware though that with most HTTP clients, this is a warning at best and not typically an error.  If you are in control of the client code, you can detect this condition by comparing the length of the data you received, to the length you expected.

Comment: did you check my code? I do req.connection.destroy(). Obviously I know about res.end(). You cannot do res.end(), you absolutely must close the connection. Do you realize that ?

Comment: Yes, I did check your code.  Use `.end()` on your socket... `.destroy()` is not what you want.  And, what do you think `res.end()` does in the situation of no keepalive?  It closes the connection.  I mention it because it might be relevant in your case.  Please re-read my answer, the two options I suggested, and pick one that applies to you.

Comment: exactly, res.end() will cause havoc in case of keepalive if non-chunked transmission is used. I'll try socket.end, didn't try it yet.

Comment: @Pavel Also note, depending on your version of Node.js, `socket.close()` might be what you need.  This API has been changed a bit over the years.

Comment: there is no socket.close in my version of node (I use latest). I tried these: `req.socket.end()`, 'req.connection.end()', 'req.connection.destroy()', `req.connection.destroy(new Error('bad data'))`, none of them trigger error event on client side and client thinks that everything was ok. IMO node has to handle properly content-length header and trigger exception, currently you can send 10-byte with 100-byte content length and it handles it as everything went well.

Comment: @Pavel Right, as I mentioned earlier, HTTP throw a warning, sometimes nothing.  Since you're in control of the client, you need to write code to determine how many bytes you have (looks like you already have that) and throw your own error.  Wrong content length is extremely common, so most HTTP clients ignore it.  (Fire up Fiddler or similar sometime, and browse the web for a bit.  Watch all the content length errors... they're everywhere.  That's why clients typically ignore this problem.)

Comment: @Pavel Let me know if that isn't clear, and I'll rewrite my answer to clarify.

Comment: But with wrong content-length and keepalive entire communication channel will fall apart isn't it? in my case because I cannot trigger error on receiver side another proxy upstream ends up `chewing` next http messages as part of body of previously corrupt message that didn't have complete body, obviously from that point on it ends up trying to parse random data as HTTP headers etc. Complete collapse. At least to prevent that error socket has to be closed even if there is no way to trigger error event on client side.

Comment: @Pavel Closing the connection sounds like what you have to do.  That will definitely cause an error (well, for any clients following RFC7230 and related).

Comment: FYI, `res.end() ` in your answer wrong: 'All you have to do is res.end()', it should be changed. If you try it, nothing will work if keep-alive is in effect: client won't even know that server had ended reply! Only if there is no keep-alive this happens to work just because ending a reply causes node to close the connection.

Comment: @Pavel Right, I meant in the case of no keep-alive like I said in my last paragraph, but I'll fix it... it is confusing.  That's what I get for answering questions after midnight.  ;-)